# WordPress get_post_meta returns a string how do I access the single key value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fix a bit of code and display an image that is set with a custom metabox. I have found the saved data in wp_postmeta and it looks like the data is saved as a string but I can see an obvious key value pair.

When I use the following code...

```
 $imgVar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'attachments', true);

 $testing4 = $imgVar;

 var_dump($testing4);
```

...I get the following output...

```
string(101) "{"my_item":[{"id":"653","fields":{"title":"mytitle","caption":"test this out"}}]}"
```

... this looks like it is telling me that the output is a string with 101 characters but I see key values and an array.

what I would like to have output is, or what it seems it should be...

```
array[0](

  "my_item" => array(
         "id" => "653",
         "fields" => array(
                "title" =>"mytitle",
                "caption" => "test this out"
            ),
    )

),
```

can someone explain what is being output for this newb :), and if it is possible to turn what is being output into a regular array. Or if I can access the key value "id => 653" without switching the output.

Thanks.

Comment: The format you are getting back is a JSON. PHP has built-in functions to very nicely do pretty much whatever you want with that - like turning it into an array.

Comment: Thanks! That is also what is being saved in the db, so is WP using JSON to save the data? Or at least that is what the data looks like in the column in the db. :)

Comment: so I think I found it... json_decode() is this right?

Comment: Yes, you can turn it into an array with `json_decode();` :)

Answer (score 1):

The output-string is probably serialized (easier for Wordpress to store data more efficient).

Try:

```
<?php maybe_unserialize( $original ) ?>
```

If you want to know more about this look at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize

Answer (score 0):

> $var = json_decode($testing4);

Answer (score 0):

Format output with `<pre>` tags

```
echo '<pre>' . var_dump($testing4) . '</pre>';
```